# Count group elements using angular-filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Is it possible using angular-filter "groupBy" (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) to count the elements in each group to use in a "badge" span (of course without using a a function doing the "manual count")

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in directoryResult | groupBy: 'TableId'">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transport"></span> {{convertTableid(key)}} <span class="badge">{{directoryResult.length}}</span>
    </a>
    <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in value">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transport"></span> {{item.Text}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some of your code; hopefully in a plunker or jsfiddle, or a code snippet. This way we can more readily see what you are trying to do. And the short answer is, yes, you can use $filter to count groups, but not sure you can get away with it without a manual count.

Comment: in the sample it show always the same length() directoryResult.length

Comment: You would probably need to do the filtered count on the JS side using $filter('grouptBy')($scope.directoryResult, "TableId") and do count there because directoryResult is the variable before it is filtered. In your HTML angular creates a new local variable which is filtered.

Comment: Also, please provide the code for the groupBy filter, angular doesn't have one natively. So please show yours.

Comment: As in my question, the groupBy is provided by the https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do something like:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in directoryResult | groupBy: 'TableId' as result"
```

then `result` will be the filtered variable. You can check the length of that for the number of groups.

**Update:**

Here is a plunker with a groupBy filter.
http://plnkr.co/edit/8jB4wSRtKfVmEsTGZtfV?p=preview

I took an existing filter I found (since angular doesn't have a built in one) and added a length property. The results show up properly.

**Update 2:**
Another plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iwUkIMjvevja7KyfTrFC?p=preview

Since angular-filter doesn't provide a length property, you have to count it yourself with `Object.keys`

```
<div>Number of groups: {{numGroups(result) }} </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.numGroups = function(input){
    return Object.keys(input).length;
}
```

**Update 3:**
the result contains an object literal: each property is named "key" and its value is a subgroup of the list. So the running solution is:

```
<div>Number of groups: {{numGroups(result[key]) }} </div>
```

**Update 4**
Finally we may get rid completly of the numGroups function, using directly:

```
<div>Number of groups: {{result[key].length}} </div>
```

So your first idea was the good one, I had just to adapt it as my groupBy resturn an object literal containing all the goruped lists.

Comment: I just tested this:<span class="badge">{{result.length}}</span> and doesn't work....

Comment: Let me set up a test plunker

Comment: @Robert Can you provide a sample JSON?

Comment: here a small sample https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzElu5N9SANUc1M5bVMtUlBnbkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Robert, I updated my answer, you have to look at your groupBy filter to see whether it has a length property, otherwise it won't work. The code I provide in the plunker defines a length property, that's why it works. Aliasing with `as result` works as well.

Comment: @Robert, I updated my answer again. Angular-filter doesn't define a length property for their groupBy filter, so you either need to define one in their code, or do a quick count using a function.

Comment: I'll try your provided groupBy as mine (well the one provided by   https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby )  doesn't look  owning a length property

Comment: First thanks for all your efforts :) You won't believe, but the input parameter I receive is a an object literal each property name is TableId, and the value is the grouped list. So the working solution is:         $scope.groupCount = function (input, value) {
            return Object.keys(input[value]).length;
        }

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the edit, glad it works. If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it.

Comment: Why doesn't this work with limitTo? Can I make it work with limitTo? http://plnkr.co/edit/LwF9OBIDS9opaYZgs831?p=preview